# Repacking RDS database with pg_repack isn't online

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

While running `pg_repack` on a RDS Postgresql 9.6.3, got this failure for one of writers:

```
ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation log_24034858
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO repack.log_24034858(pk, row) 
VALUES(CASE WHEN $1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE (ROW($1.id)::repack.pk_24034858) END, $2)"
```

But `pg_repack` should allow writes to repacked tables, why did it fail here?

Answer (score 7):

We [found a similar issue](http://engineering.ometria.com/2018/01/29/using-pg_repack-with-aws-postgres-rds/). The issue appears to be that log tables created in the repack schema don't have the correct permissions. Our solution was to use ALTER DEFAULT PRIVALEGES to fix this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_repack;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA repack GRANT INSERT ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA repack GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO PUBLIC;
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.pg_repack) you have to create `pg_repack` extension from your superuser account. But the extension is created with `rds_superuser` role instead. And all other objects are created with that role as owner, for example:

```
=> \dnS+ repack                                                                                 │ 
                     List of schemas                                                                    │ subsidy | birth_month | birth_year
  Name  |     Owner     | Access privileges | Description                                               │---------+-------------+------------
--------+---------------+-------------------+-------------                                              │       1 |           7 |       1952
 repack | rds_superuser |                   |                                                           │       1 |           7 |       1952
(1 row)
```

You shouldn't change owner of schema. And you probably don't want to `REASSIGN OWNED ...`. It is sufficient to change owner for each function in `repack` namespace to fix permission problems:

```
create extension pg_repack;
ALTER FUNCTION repack.version() OWNER TO postgres;                                                                                                                                                             
ALTER FUNCTION repack.version_sql() OWNER TO postgres;                                                
ALTER FUNCTION repack.array_accum(anyelement) OWNER TO postgres;                                      
ALTER FUNCTION repack.oid2text(oid) OWNER TO postgres;                                                
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_index_columns(oid,text) OWNER TO postgres;                                  
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_order_by(oid,oid) OWNER TO postgres;                                        
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_create_index_type(oid,name) OWNER TO postgres;                              
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_create_trigger(oid,oid) OWNER TO postgres;                                  
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_enable_trigger(oid) OWNER TO postgres;                                      
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_assign(oid,text) OWNER TO postgres;                                         
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_compare_pkey(oid,text) OWNER TO postgres;                                   
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_columns_for_create_as(oid) OWNER TO postgres;                               
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_drop_columns(oid,text) OWNER TO postgres;                                   
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_storage_param(oid) OWNER TO postgres;                                       
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_alter_col_storage(oid) OWNER TO postgres;                                   
ALTER FUNCTION repack.repack_indexdef(oid,oid,name,boolean) OWNER TO postgres;                        
ALTER FUNCTION repack.repack_trigger() OWNER TO postgres;                                             
ALTER FUNCTION repack.conflicted_triggers(oid) OWNER TO postgres;                                     
ALTER FUNCTION repack.disable_autovacuum(regclass) OWNER TO postgres;                                 
ALTER FUNCTION repack.repack_apply(cstring,cstring,cstring,cstring,cstring,integer) OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER FUNCTION repack.repack_swap(oid) OWNER TO postgres;                                             
ALTER FUNCTION repack.repack_drop(oid,integer) OWNER TO postgres;                                     
ALTER FUNCTION repack.repack_index_swap(oid) OWNER TO postgres;                                       
ALTER FUNCTION repack.get_table_and_inheritors(regclass) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Is this documentend somewhere? This is also need for non onwers users creating data

Comment: this was nowhere documented, so I posted question-answer here, for people to discover fast. Probably we should report bug to Amazon

Comment: I think this is issue of pg_repack it self. I had to set the onwer to another write-enabled group I use for some users.

Comment: opened an issue: https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/issues/146 doing this created other problems